# How to generate multiple lines in PDF using Apache pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I am using Pdfbox to generate PDF files using Java. The problem is that when i add long text contents in the document, it is not displayed properly. Only a part of it is displayed. That too in a single line.

I want text to be in multiple lines.

My code is given below:

```
PDPageContentStream pdfContent=new PDPageContentStream(pdfDocument, pdfPage, true, true);

pdfContent.beginText();
pdfContent.setFont(pdfFont, 11);
pdfContent.moveTextPositionByAmount(30,750);            
pdfContent.drawString("I am trying to create a PDF file with a lot of text contents in the document. I am using PDFBox");
pdfContent.endText();
```

My output:

[image: This is my output file]

Comment: Working example is here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308964/how-to-add-multiple-pages-in-pdfbox/41925284#41925284

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Adding to the answer of Mark you might want to know where to split your long string. You can use the `PDFont` method `getStringWidth` for that.

Putting everything together you get something like this (with minor differences depending on the PDFBox version):

#### PDFBox 1.8.x

```
PDDocument doc = null;
try
{
    doc = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    doc.addPage(page);
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);

    PDFont pdfFont = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
    float fontSize = 25;
    float leading = 1.5f * fontSize;

    PDRectangle mediabox = page.getMediaBox();
    float margin = 72;
    float width = mediabox.getWidth() - 2*margin;
    float startX = mediabox.getLowerLeftX() + margin;
    float startY = mediabox.getUpperRightY() - margin;

    String text = "I am trying to create a PDF file with a lot of text contents in the document. I am using PDFBox"; 
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    int lastSpace = -1;
    while (text.length() > 0)
    {
        int spaceIndex = text.indexOf(' ', lastSpace + 1);
        if (spaceIndex < 0)
            spaceIndex = text.length();
        String subString = text.substring(0, spaceIndex);
        float size = fontSize * pdfFont.getStringWidth(subString) / 1000;
        System.out.printf("'%s' - %f of %f\n", subString, size, width);
        if (size > width)
        {
            if (lastSpace < 0)
                lastSpace = spaceIndex;
            subString = text.substring(0, lastSpace);
            lines.add(subString);
            text = text.substring(lastSpace).trim();
            System.out.printf("'%s' is line\n", subString);
            lastSpace = -1;
        }
        else if (spaceIndex == text.length())
        {
            lines.add(text);
            System.out.printf("'%s' is line\n", text);
            text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            lastSpace = spaceIndex;
        }
    }
        
    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);
    contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(startX, startY);            
    for (String line: lines)
    {
        contentStream.drawString(line);
        contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(0, -leading);
    }
    contentStream.endText(); 
    contentStream.close();

    doc.save("break-long-string.pdf");
}
finally
{
    if (doc != null)
    {
        doc.close();
    }
}
```

*([BreakLongString.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/content/BreakLongString.java#L40) test `testBreakString` for PDFBox 1.8.x)*

#### PDFBox 2.0.x

```
PDDocument doc = null;
try
{
    doc = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage();
    doc.addPage(page);
    PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);

    PDFont pdfFont = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
    float fontSize = 25;
    float leading = 1.5f * fontSize;

    PDRectangle mediabox = page.getMediaBox();
    float margin = 72;
    float width = mediabox.getWidth() - 2*margin;
    float startX = mediabox.getLowerLeftX() + margin;
    float startY = mediabox.getUpperRightY() - margin;

    String text = "I am trying to create a PDF file with a lot of text contents in the document. I am using PDFBox"; 
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    int lastSpace = -1;
    while (text.length() > 0)
    {
        int spaceIndex = text.indexOf(' ', lastSpace + 1);
        if (spaceIndex < 0)
            spaceIndex = text.length();
        String subString = text.substring(0, spaceIndex);
        float size = fontSize * pdfFont.getStringWidth(subString) / 1000;
        System.out.printf("'%s' - %f of %f\n", subString, size, width);
        if (size > width)
        {
            if (lastSpace < 0)
                lastSpace = spaceIndex;
            subString = text.substring(0, lastSpace);
            lines.add(subString);
            text = text.substring(lastSpace).trim();
            System.out.printf("'%s' is line\n", subString);
            lastSpace = -1;
        }
        else if (spaceIndex == text.length())
        {
            lines.add(text);
            System.out.printf("'%s' is line\n", text);
            text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            lastSpace = spaceIndex;
        }
    }

    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);
    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(startX, startY);
    for (String line: lines)
    {
        contentStream.showText(line);
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, -leading);
    }
    contentStream.endText(); 
    contentStream.close();

    doc.save(new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "break-long-string.pdf"));
}
finally
{
    if (doc != null)
    {
        doc.close();
    }
}
```

*([BreakLongString.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/BreakLongString.java#L39) test `testBreakString` for PDFBox 2.0.x)*

#### The result

[image: Screenshot of the result PDF displayed in Acrobat Reader]

This looks as expected.

Of course there are numerous improvements to make but this should show how to do it.

#### Adding unconditional line breaks

In a comment aleskv asked:

> could you add line breaks when there are \n in the string?

One can easily extend the solution to unconditionally break at newline characters by first splitting the string at '\n' characters and then iterating over the split result.

E.g. if instead of the long string from above

```
String text = "I am trying to create a PDF file with a lot of text contents in the document. I am using PDFBox";
```

you want to process this even longer string with embedded new line characters

```
String textNL = "I am trying to create a PDF file with a lot of text contents in the document. I am using PDFBox.\nFurthermore, I have added some newline characters to the string at which lines also shall be broken.\nIt should work alright like this...";
```

you can simply replace

```
String text = "I am trying to create a PDF file with a lot of text contents in the document. I am using PDFBox"; 
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
int lastSpace = -1;
while (text.length() > 0)
{
    [...]
}
```

in the solutions above by

```
String textNL = "I am trying to create a PDF file with a lot of text contents in the document. I am using PDFBox.\nFurthermore, I have added some newline characters to the string at which lines also shall be broken.\nIt should work alright like this..."; 
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String text : textNL.split("\n"))
{
    int lastSpace = -1;
    while (text.length() > 0)
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

*(from [BreakLongString.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/BreakLongString.java#L220) test `testBreakStringNL`)*

The result:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you also want your text to be justified, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20681996/1729265) improving the sample here.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but currently it doesn't support the case when the word is longer than the maximum width of the line. In that case, the word needs to be broken but the code doesn't do that.

Comment: *"In that case, the word needs to be broken but the code doesn't do that."* - Whether in that case the word needs to be broken or needs to exceed the line borders, depends on the use case at hand. As proper word breaking, i.e. language-specific hyphenation, is a topic in its own right, I here implemented the alternative solution.

Comment: could you add line breaks when there are \n in the string?

Comment: @aleskv Yes, quite easily. I have added a new section "Adding unconditional line breaks" to the answer covering that.

Comment: @mkl I am facing:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at
PDFont pdfFont = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
in both PDFBox 1.8.x and 2.0.x
Any solution? (have googled a lot)

Comment: @sifr_dot_in that sounds weird. Make that a question in its own right and provide additional data, in particular the full stack trace.

Answer (score 10):

I know it's a bit late, but i had a little problem with mkl's solution. If the last line would only contain one word, your algorithm writes it on the previous one.

For Example: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" is your text and it should add a line break after "sit".

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet
```

But it does this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

I came up with my own solution i want to share with you.

```
/**
 * @param text The text to write on the page.
 * @param x The position on the x-axis.
 * @param y The position on the y-axis.
 * @param allowedWidth The maximum allowed width of the whole text (e.g. the width of the page - a defined margin).
 * @param page The page for the text.
 * @param contentStream The content stream to set the text properties and write the text.
 * @param font The font used to write the text.
 * @param fontSize The font size used to write the text.
 * @param lineHeight The line height of the font (typically 1.2 * fontSize or 1.5 * fontSize).
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void drawMultiLineText(String text, int x, int y, int allowedWidth, PDPage page, PDPageContentStream contentStream, PDFont font, int fontSize, int lineHeight) throws IOException {

    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    String myLine = "";

    // get all words from the text
    // keep in mind that words are separated by spaces -> "Lorem ipsum!!!!:)" -> words are "Lorem" and "ipsum!!!!:)"
    String[] words = text.split(" ");
    for(String word : words) {

        if(!myLine.isEmpty()) {
            myLine += " ";
        }

        // test the width of the current line + the current word
        int size = (int) (fontSize * font.getStringWidth(myLine + word) / 1000);
        if(size > allowedWidth) {
            // if the line would be too long with the current word, add the line without the current word
            lines.add(myLine);

            // and start a new line with the current word
            myLine = word;
        } else {
            // if the current line + the current word would fit, add the current word to the line
            myLine += word;
        }
    }
    // add the rest to lines
    lines.add(myLine);

    for(String line : lines) {
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont(font, fontSize);
        contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(x, y);
        contentStream.drawString(line);
        contentStream.endText();

        y -= lineHeight;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, as I commented in my answer the case `(spaceIndex < 0)` (i.e. last word) should be handled differently. Your answer reminded me to actually update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

```
///// FOR PDBOX 2.0.X
//  FOR ADDING DYNAMIC PAGE ACCORDING THE LENGTH OF THE CONTENT

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;

public class Document_Creation {

   public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {

       PDDocument doc = null;
       try
       {
           doc = new PDDocument();
           PDPage page = new PDPage();
           doc.addPage(page);
           PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);

           PDFont pdfFont = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
           float fontSize = 25;
           float leading = 1.5f * fontSize;

           PDRectangle mediabox = page.getMediaBox();
           float margin = 72;
           float width = mediabox.getWidth() - 2*margin;
           float startX = mediabox.getLowerLeftX() + margin;
           float startY = mediabox.getUpperRightY() - margin;

           String text = "I am trying to create a PDF file with a lot of text contents in the document. I am using PDFBox.An essay is, generally, a piece of writing that gives the author's own argument — but the definition is vague, overlapping with those of an article, a pamphlet, and a short story. Essays have traditionally been sub-classified as formal and informal. Formal essays are characterized by serious purpose, dignity, logical organization, length,whereas the informal essay is characterized by the personal element (self-revelation, individual tastes and experiences, confidential manner), humor, graceful style, rambling structure, unconventionality or novelty of theme.Lastly, one of the most attractive features of cats as housepets is their ease of care. Cats do not have to be walked. They get plenty of exercise in the house as they play, and they do their business in the litter box. Cleaning a litter box is a quick, painless procedure. Cats also take care of their own grooming. Bathing a cat is almost never necessary because under ordinary circumstances cats clean themselves. Cats are more particular about personal cleanliness than people are. In addition, cats can be left home alone for a few hours without fear. Unlike some pets, most cats will not destroy the furnishings when left alone. They are content to go about their usual activities until their owners return."; 
           List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
           int lastSpace = -1;
           while (text.length() > 0)
           {
               int spaceIndex = text.indexOf(' ', lastSpace + 1);
               if (spaceIndex < 0)
                   spaceIndex = text.length();
               String subString = text.substring(0, spaceIndex);
               float size = fontSize * pdfFont.getStringWidth(subString) / 1000;
               System.out.printf("'%s' - %f of %f\n", subString, size, width);
               if (size > width)
               {
                   if (lastSpace < 0)
                       lastSpace = spaceIndex;
                   subString = text.substring(0, lastSpace);
                   lines.add(subString);
                   text = text.substring(lastSpace).trim();
                   System.out.printf("'%s' is line\n", subString);
                   lastSpace = -1;
               }
               else if (spaceIndex == text.length())
               {
                   lines.add(text);
                   System.out.printf("'%s' is line\n", text);
                   text = "";
               }
               else
               {
                   lastSpace = spaceIndex;
               }
           }

           contentStream.beginText();
           contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);
           contentStream.newLineAtOffset(startX, startY);
           float currentY=startY;
           for (String line: lines)
           {
               currentY -=leading;

               if(currentY<=margin)
               {

                   contentStream.endText(); 
                   contentStream.close();
                   PDPage new_Page = new PDPage();
                   doc.addPage(new_Page);
                   contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, new_Page);
                   contentStream.beginText();
                   contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);
                   contentStream.newLineAtOffset(startX, startY);
                   currentY=startY;
               }
               contentStream.showText(line);
               contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, -leading);
           }
           contentStream.endText(); 
           contentStream.close();

           doc.save("C:/Users/VINAYAK/Desktop/docccc/break-long-string.pdf");
       }
       finally
       {
           if (doc != null)
           {
               doc.close();
           }
       }

   }  
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Could you explain how and why this solves op's problem?

Comment: This is just an additional approach to earlier answer to solve the issue if text is too long which can't be set in single page.

Answer (score 4):

Just draw the string in a position below, typically done within a loop:

```
float textx = margin+cellMargin;
float texty = y-15;
for(int i = 0; i < content.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0 ; j < content[i].length; j++){
        String text = content[i][j];
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(textx,texty);
        contentStream.drawString(text);
        contentStream.endText();
        textx += colWidth;
    }
    texty-=rowHeight;
    textx = margin+cellMargin;
}
```

These are the important lines:

```
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(textx,texty);
contentStream.drawString(text);
contentStream.endText();
```

Just keep drawing new strings in new positions. For an example using a table, see here:
http://fahdshariff.blogspot.ca/2010/10/creating-tables-with-pdfbox.html

Comment: I assume @Ronald searches a way to insert text without having to break the lines manually or at least having methods to support line breaking according to character length.

Comment: @mkl This is what exactly i meant.

Answer (score 2):

contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(textx,texty) is key point.

say for example if you are using a A4 size means 580,800 is width and height correspondling(approximately). so you have move your text based on the position of your document size.

PDFBox supports varies page format . so the height and width will vary for different page format

Comment: This could be a comment instead of answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Pdfbox-layout](https://github.com/ralfstuckert/pdfbox-layout) abstracts out all the tedious details of managing the layout. As a complete Kotlin example, here is how to convert a text file to a pdf without worrying about line wrapping and pagination.

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font
import rst.pdfbox.layout.elements.Document
import rst.pdfbox.layout.elements.Paragraph
import java.io.File

fun main() {
    val textFile = "input.txt"
    val pdfFile = "output.pdf"
    val font = PDType1Font.COURIER
    val fontSize = 12f

    val document = Document(40f, 50f, 40f, 60f)
    val paragraph = Paragraph()
    File(textFile).forEachLine {
        paragraph.addText("$it\n", fontSize, font)
    }
    document.add(paragraph)
    document.save(File(pdfFile))
}
```