# How to make justify formating for paragraph in pdfbox Example given below, any suggestion?

Tags: pdfbox, justify

Problem :- Not able to apply justify formatting for paragraph in pdfbox.

I tried :- I included space in between words so that it justifies the paragraph. But this does not work for a variable width font. For that I not able to identify pixel position for each character since the width in pixels of each character is different.

Please give suggestions....

I want to make this type of alignment in pdfbox as given below :-

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to justify text in PDFBOX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680430/is-it-possible-to-justify-text-in-pdfbox)