# Remove illegal characters from string with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

When I try to write illegal characters to a PDF I obviously get an exception. E.g.

```
contentStream.showText("some illegal characters");    
...
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: U+000A ('controlLF') is not available in this font Helvetica (generic: ArialMT) encoding: WinAnsiEncoding...
```

How can I find out which characters are not supported and strip them from the string?

Comment: Usually you can count on a font not to contain glyphs for characters in the control character range < U+0020. Which characters exactly are available depends on the font in question and the declared encoding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is my solution... at least it works for what I need. I used the WinAnsiEncoding class of PDFBox and called the contains method to check if the character is supported.

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.encoding.WinAnsiEncoding;

public class Test extends WinAnsiEncoding {

    public static String remove(String test) {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
            if (WinAnsiEncoding.INSTANCE.contains(test.charAt(i))) {
                b.append(test.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return b.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(remove("abc\rcde"));
        // prints abccde
    }

}
```

Comment: How can I add a new line between the strings that going to be written on PDF ? both \n and System.getProperty("line.separator") not working ... Please help

Comment: You have to split the string at the new line characters and manually write line by line. There is no other solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635275/how-to-generate-multiple-lines-in-pdf-using-apache-pdfbox

Comment: How can I utilize the same code for a custom font loaded using (for example) `PDType0Font font = PDType0Font.load(document, new File("Amiri-Regular.ttf"));` ?

Comment: Still getting the error: No glyph for U+0009 in font FreeSans