# Apache PDFBox Java library- text not getting rendered

Tags: java, apache, pdf, graphics, pdfbox

I am using the Apache PDFBox java library to create PDFs. However, I am facing problem in rendering multi-line text (line wrap):

```
//Creating PDF document object 
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();

//Adding the blank page to the document
doc.addPage( new PDPage() );

PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);
PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\abc.png", doc);

PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page); 
contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 10, 720);

//Begin the Content stream 
contentStream.beginText(); 
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(50, 735);

//Setting the font to the Content stream
contentStream.setFont( PDType1Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 16 );
contentStream. showText("ABC Management System");

//Setting the leading
//contentStream.setLeading(14.5f);

//Setting the position for the line
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(25, 600);

String text1 = "This is an example of adding text to a page in the pdf document we can add as many lines";
String text2 = "as we want like this using the ShowText()  method of the ContentStream class";

//Adding text in the form of string
contentStream. showText(text1);
contentStream.newLine();
contentStream. showText(text2);

//Ending the content stream
contentStream.endText();

System.out.println("Content added");

//Closing the content stream
contentStream.close();

//Saving the document
doc.save("my_doc.pdf");

System.out.println("PDF created");  

//Closing the document  
doc.close();
```

The issue I am faciing is the latter half of the text (text1, text2) is not getting rendered in the PDF file. Only the image and the first line `ABC Management System` is displayed in the pdf.

To generate multi-line texts, I referred: [PDFBox - Adding Multiple Lines](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pdfbox/pdfbox_adding_multiple_lines.htm).

I do not understand what `setLeading` does and hence commented it out and tried again but the text was still not getting rendered.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr It worked. Thanks!

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Is there any way to change background color?

Comment: You'll have to draw a rectangle in the appropriate non stroking color.

Comment: @HBK for more automatic line breaking you might want to look for inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19683618/1729265).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newLineAtOffset()` is relative to the current text position. To restart from 0, the easiest is to end your current and start a new text block. Your current code places you at y 1335 (or slightly lower, depending of the leading).

Comment: Is there any shortcut way to do line wrap? Right now, we have to break a line into two strings to achieve that.

Comment: No. PDFBox is low level, unlike itext. You'll have to do line wrap / page wrap yourself.