# how to make new line with breaking specific length line using pdf box

Tags: groovy, pdfbox

i want make my output like this

```
      lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet
```

i already tried with this code:

```
contentStream.beginText()
contentStream.setFont(font, 12)
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(80, 160)
contentStream.drawString(addressOffice)
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(-30, -15)
contentStream.drawString(addressOffice)
contentStream.endText()
```

but this did not solved my problem because it simply placed the same value for new line like this:

```
       lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

the addressOffice is a value parameter.

Comment: If you draw the same string twice, you'll get the same string twice. Thus, you have to split it up yourself. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19683618/1729265) illustrates how to do that manually. If you'd prefer some additional library on top of PDFBox to do that for you, have a look at e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65270709/1729265).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so as pointed out in the comments your problem is repeating the parameter `addressOffice` in both lines of code.  Hence it writes the string twice.  Here is how you fix that in groovy.

```
contentStream.beginText()
contentStream.setFont(font, 12)
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(80, 160)
contentStream.drawString(addressOffice[0..10])
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(-30, -15)
contentStream.drawString(addressOffice[12..-1])
contentStream.endText()
```

The ranges (ie 0..10) split the string by the indexes of the range.  Zero being the start of the string, and 10 is just after "lorem ipsum".  The next range skips the whitespace and picks up at "dolor sit amet", and the -1 tells Groovy we want the end of the String.

Of course these indexes are very much tied to your input string and generally you'd want some way to determine the split point (ie 10 and 12) programmatically, but given the information provided to us we can't answer that for you.