# How to set multiline value to PDField

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox 1.8.x for filling out an acroform in a PDF document. For this, I'm iterating over all PDFields in the document and setting the correct values which are stored in my HashMap (aParameter).

```
  PDAcroForm acroform = aTemplate.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
  List fields = acroform.getFields();
  for(int i=0; i<fields.size(); i++)
  {
    PDField field = (PDField) fields.get(i);
    String lValue = aParameter.get(field.getPartialName());
    if(lValue != null) field.setValue(lValue);
    field.setReadonly(true);   
  }
```

It's working very great except for my one and only multiline textbox. In my resulting PDF, the correct text is in my multiline textbox, but without any new lines. While searching for reasons I found some very old answers that PDFBox doesn't support multilines, it can't set a new line character on it's own. Is this behavior still up to date? Or are there any possibilities to automatically break the text to a new line, when the width of the textbox is reached?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598099/how-to-insert-a-linefeed-with-pdfbox-drawstring/15205956#15205956) looks like a solution, but they are using another technique (drawString) to write the PDF. Is there a possibility to modify this idea to match my behavior of filling out PDFields?

I'm happy about any ideas!

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest version (1.8.8), there were recent bugfixes in acroforms.

Comment: I used the latest version too, it's not working there.

Comment: Sorry to bring bad news, it's indeed not working properly yet, see PDFBOX-2333 and PDFBOX-1402.

Comment: :( that's a really bad news. Do you know about any workaround? I actually need to fix this soon.

Comment: Sorry, no. I'm not involed with this myself, but I did once scratch the surface and so I know that appearance strings of Acroform fields are really tricky.