# Parse TinyMCE body content to plain text with style

Tags: javascript, java, jsoup

I am storing TinyMCE body content in database for description,
Example:

```html
<p><strong>Hello, World!</strong></p><p style="padding-left: 30px;" data-mce-style="padding-left: 30px;"><em>one&nbsp;</em></p><p style="padding-left: 30px;" data-mce-style="padding-left: 30px;"><em>two</em></p><p style="padding-left: 30px;" data-mce-style="padding-left: 30px;"><em>three</em></p>
```

Now i want to create pdf of this description with keeping the formatting of text.
so whatever output we see after running above code should be present in pdf with same formatting. Pdf generation logic is in java class.
So I am getting this description out of database and want to parse with keeping formatting and add it to pdf.
I tried using Jsoup parser but it's not applying styles!
So is there way to do this?

Comment: I asked a similar question a while back. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482644/generate-pdf-from-json-object-containing-content-from-tinymce-html The solution I came up with might help you. I hope.